# Converting Stripe's creatToken into Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I've built most of an android app in Kotlin. now I'm using the stripe payment library and I can't convert the following routine into Kotlin.

```
 stripe.createToken(
                    cardtoSave,
                    new TokenCallback {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            // Send token to your server
                        }
                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            // Show localized error message
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    }
            )
```

Just not sure if it us possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, we can implement that in Kotlin. Try this below code

```
stripe.createToken(card, object : TokenCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(token: Token?) {
                Log.v("Token!","Token Created!!"+ token!!.getId())
                chargeCard(token!!.getId()); // Pass that token to your Server for further processing
            }

            override fun onError(error: Exception?) {
                Log.v("Token!","Token Not Created!!")
                error!!.printStackTrace()
            }

        })
```

You can refer [Stripe-Kotlin](http://yamikrish.blogspot.in/2017/12/stripe-integration-in-android-kotlin.html) for full stripe integration using Kotlin

Comment: much obliged! for your response